# How close is $h^0(mD)$ to be a polynomial?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-surfaces, divisors, line-bundles

Let $X$ be a normal (or smooth if it helps) projective variety over an algebraically closed field $k$. Fix a Cartier divisor $D$: I am interested in knowing how $h^0(mD)$ behaves as $m$ varies.

At page 171 in Lazarsfeld's book "Positivity in Algebraic Geometry, I" there are some results in this direction. Above all, there are a result of Zariski about surfaces (see below), and the famous theorem by Kollàr and Matsusaka. Is there anything else worth to be mentioned? Or more recent?

In particular, I would like to know whether there are analogues to Zariski's result (then refined by Cutkosky and Srninivas) saying that on a smooth (I think the generalization includes the normal case) surface, given $D \geq 0$, then $h^0(mD)$ is a polynomial up to a bounded error, which is periodic in $m$. Is there anything like this in higher dimension? Are there examples that show this is not the case?

Comment: For Toric variety it is e Ehrhart polynomial

Comment: http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ajm/1088090062 and http://www.jstor.org/stable/40068042?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents also PhD thesis of  Mourougane ,  https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~demailly/theses/mourougane_these_1997.pdf

Comment: http://sebastien.boucksom.perso.math.cnrs.fr/publis/Okounkov_Bourbaki.pdf

Comment: The Annals paper of Cutkosky-Srinivas contains a higher-dimensional counterexample.